# How to get all tables that have FKs to another table?

Tags: oracle, foreign-keys

Is there any way to get all tables that have foreign keys to another table in oracle with a query?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Perhaps you could restate it, or offer an example?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here is [a good article](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/oracle/article.php/3665591/Finding-Foreign-Key-Constraints-in-Oracle.htm) with an answer:

```
select owner,constraint_name,constraint_type,table_name,r_owner,r_constraint_name
from all_constraints 
where constraint_type='R'
and r_constraint_name in (select constraint_name from all_constraints 
where constraint_type in ('P','U') and table_name='TABLE_NAME');
```

Comment: I'll check that view - the query returns the table that has the FK, and I'd need to specify one table and get every other table that has a FK to it

Comment: I edited it with the correct query from the article, so I could accept it

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that both the parent and child tables are in the same schema do the following:

```
select t1.table_name child_table, t1.constraint_name, t2.table_name parent_table

from user_constraints t1, user_constraints t2

where t1.r_constraint_name = t2.constraint_name
```

Note that r_constraint_name is populated only for FK (type 'R') constraints, so the self-join only returns info of interest

Answer (score 0):

if we know the parent key, just altered juan 's answer with employees table

```
select *
from user_constraints 
where R_CONSTRAINT_NAME='EMP_EMP_ID_PK'
and constraint_type='R'
```